# Anti aliasing DrawLine on CE

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am drawing a line to a `Graphics` object in Windows CE using C#.NET 3.5.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(11, 118, 200), 2), x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

This works however looks terrible due to jaggies etc.  Is there anyway I can draw anti aliased lines?

From what I can tell the `Graphics` object doesn't support this natively but is there anyway to "cheat" this effect using some trickery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fast trick if you're drawing on a solid color background, you can draw a line with a thicker pen and a color in between the background color and the line color prior to the actual line, for instance, when drawing on a black background:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(5, 59, 100), 3), x1, y1, x2, y2);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(11, 118, 200), 2), x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

This adds a "glow" to the line (even on perfect horizontal / vertical lines though).

Comment: Not perfect but definitely is an easy way to improve the way it looks! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain. I was doing something similar a few years ago for .NETCF and I was going down all sorts of funny paths. Ended up more work than it was worth. Have a look at this awfulness:

http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_wuline.htm

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/b34f56c4-585b-4ff5-ac7d-b6e2ae516ccf/

Also, this might serve some answers but could be a useful replacement for the WM GDI system.

http://drawingcf.codeplex.com/

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705653/anti-aliased-rounded-corners-in-windows-ce-6-0) lead me to the http://www.amanithvg.com/project.html which offers an OpenGL like framework with Windows CE libraries. Might be mega-overkill though just for a few lines.

Finally, you could always just use a bitmap, but you might have problems with transparency later on.

Comment: probably is too much work implementing some of those suggestions - thanks though!

Comment: @Chris I absolutely agree with you on that!

Answer (score 1):

Found this XrossGDI+ complete native C#:

http://www.isquaredsoftware.com/XrossOneGDIPlus.php